# Bad answer from python os.system `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to port a bash script to python. The bash script runs a `tc` command to simulate slow network, main bit goes like this:

```
tc class add dev wlp1s0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 0.5mbps &&
tc qdisc add dev wlp1s0 parent 1:12 netem delay 300ms loss 2%
```

The script "just" works running as sudo.

The exact same lines in python fail, they're looking like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("sudo tc class add dev wlp1s0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 0.5mbps")
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
512
>>> os.system("sudo tc qdisc add dev wlp1s0 parent 1:12 netem delay 300ms loss 2%")
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
512
```

In similar questions people suggests a kernel module is missing, I find this situation different since the `tc` command works perfectly when run from a terminal. It seems like python itself is missing something to be able to run it properly.
Any suggestions or links are most welcome. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

After some more reading and a pointer from the comments I've now updated the script to use `subprocess.call()`. This is supposed to replace `os.system` calls but causes no change to my issue at hand.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call("tc class add dev wlp1s0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 1.2mbit", shell=True)
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
2
```

Comment: Please please use `subprocess` instead of deprecated `os.system`..

Comment: Hi @heemayl I followed your advice with the same results. `subprocess.call(same_command, shell=True)` with the same output: `RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

tc does not work properly with sudo, You should use python to run another python file as root

Main file

```
import os
os.system("sudo python otherScript.py")
```

otherScript.py

```
import os
os.system("{tc command}")...
```

Comment: I cant get tc to work on my computer at all, dont know what is up

Comment: tc does not support 1:1 or 1:12, use 1 or 2 or 1 or 12 instead

Comment: hi @mjz19910 , can you elaborate on your answer? you don't need to be familiar with `tc` , I just don't understand why your suggestion is different from what I have right now. In any case I tried your suggestion with the same results. but was wondering if you could explain further why you think this is the solution.

Comment: Make sure you `modprobe sch_htb` first, or tc wont work, once you do that get back to me, Then we can check more, other than that, you can use either method, i dont think i can make an answer out of that, so you can just try it, let me know if it works.